Recommendation as for DC-DC and LDO for ARM and digital ICs
At the moment I work on designing a device and I can't understand which principle/rules should be used to select a DC/DC and LDO for power supplying digital ICs. I have the following ICs - 6 sensor with I2C bus, GNSS on a separate pcb, ARM STM32, display control, display backlight, LAN. All ICs are powered from 3.3 volts. The two additional sensors are powered by 5 volts. The device will be powered from general external AC/DC 120-220/5V, backup power from 12 volts.
My vision is the following: 12 volts step down to 5 volts using a low-noise DC-DC. Then 5 volts step down to 3.3 volts using a low-noise LDO. I need to power 11 chips so that there is minimal impact on all 11 chips between each other and I would like to pass EMC/EMI Testing and Certification. Also, I don't understand if I need to use a Ripple Blocker LDO for each IC? When laying out a PCB, how often should ground layers be used? Device will not be produced in the millions and I would not like to save on the components.

There's only two questions and otherwise a general request for recommendations, which could be changed to be a bit more specific or removed. However, for the actual questions, do you mean Ethernet with LAN?

Justme, Yes, Ethernet with LAN IC 10/100 Base-T.

I’d suggest you start with determining the current consumption for each device. From what you’ve mentioned, devices like the ethernet phy will be reasonably hungry - 100’s of mA along with the display backlight. I’d normally fall towards the worst case consumption. Once you’ve got these numbers you can determine the overall current for each of the voltage rails.
You would generally choose linear regulators where you have analog circuitry and/or low current requirements.
Say you need 1A at 3V3. Using a linear regulator (LDO, but not all of them are low dropout voltage!) with 5V in, 3V3 out you’re going to lose 1.7V times 1A = 1.7W in heat. If we use a LM1117 type reg in a SOT223 package, the C/W rating might be 70C/W (this is a guess). So for 1.7W, the temperature of that device is going to be rather toasty at around 120C. So that would not be an ideal solution. You would probably use a buck style converter and/or LDOs for the lower current devices.
Also consider if you have your supply rails going off board - you might want to use separate regulators for those.
Your pcb should be a minimum of 4 layer with an inner layer being your ground plane. With switching converters, be sure to follow the manufacturer’s layout and component selections. This is critical.
Also be aware of the DC bias derating with high value ceramic capacitors. Eg: a 10uF 6V3 ceramic will be unlikely to give you more than 50% of the rated capacitance at 5V.
In engineering, there is rarely only one solution, so it becomes a matter of determining your requirements and devising a solution to meet these. There can be tradeoffs for cost/size/performance.
When designing pcbs - have a look at the designs of similar devices to get design hints. Things like set top boxes and wireless routers have similar design challenges to yours. The assumption is that the designers were highly skilled and the product passed EMC testing.
What is a ‘ripple blocker LDO’?? Link to an example please.
This is not an answer per se, but guidance in order to satisfy your question. Hopefully I’ve given some hints to enable you to better research your problem.

Some Micrel parts used Ripple Blocker Technology, which was trademark of Micrel. See for example the MIC94325/45/55 500mA LDO datasheet. Micrel now seem to be part of Microchip Technologly.

This is the voltage and current consumption of some ICs: 5 volts-0.5A, 3.3 volts-0.05A, 3.3 volts-0.07A, 3.3 volts-0.08A, 3.3 volts-0.1A. I described the goals and requirements at the very beginning. Detailed information https://www.digikey.com/es/product-highlight/m/micrel/ripple-blocker
